# Change username to which my commits are credited on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

**Problem**

At some point in time, I used the command `git config --global user.name = "MyUsername"`, but the way to do this is actually `git config --global user.name "MyUsername"`, so what happened was that my username was set to `=`.

I have since changed this back to MyUsername, but my commits are still being credited to `=` in the graphs on GitLab. The email-address is correct though.

[image: Wrong GitLab username]

**Question**

Is there a way to change this username? The commits are credited to my correct email-address, so I guess there should be a way to simply change which username is linked to that email address?

**Caveats**

My profile page shows my correct username.

[image]

Side note: Private Gitlab server.

My commits also show up with the correct username. Example:

[image]

Comment: `git filter-branch --env-filter` could help. Please read about `--env-filter` in Examples part of `git filter-branch --help`.

Comment: It's possible but this is going to rewrite history (hashes) of those commits as hash calculation takes author names into account. If there are others using your repo rewriting history is not recommended.

Comment: @NishantShreshth - Yeah, that's pretty much out of the question. While the group is small (< 10 developers), the project is large, and I have no confidence in my ability to safely rewrite history.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, here is how to do it.

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email

If you want to run the script they mention

```
    $ git filter-branch --env-filter '
WRONG_EMAIL="wrong@example.com"
NEW_NAME="New Name Value"
NEW_EMAIL="correct@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

you need to open up the C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe shell, or on Linux wherever you keep that.

Then once you open up the shell prompt you can paste in the script.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @paper1111 Done. actually, I can back and added content before I saw your comment. Also, the link works for me, not sure why it doesn't for you.

Comment: Not sure why it got a down vote.  The script works.  But probably missing an explanation -- it will recreate an additional commit for each commit that has the "wrong" committer/author email.  And then the commit would be inserted between the "wrong" commit's child and parent.  And the script only checks and fixes the current branch (in case it matters).